# Debugging a VS Code theme with various themes does not work

Tags: json, debugging, visual-studio-code, themes

**Hello everyone,**

So I have been working on Serendipity for VS Code but I have the issue of launch.json not launching the theme I want to debug, I currently have 7 themes in the folder.

So I have been debugging the themes on a different folder then pasting the code on the main folder.

I was wondering if there's a way to be able to debug all the themes on the same project may be by modifying the launch.json is the right solution?

This is the repo:

- https://github.com/michael-andreuzza/serendipity

This is how my launch.json file looks:

```
{
 "version": "0.2.0",
 "configurations": [
        {
 "name": "Extension",
 "type": "extensionHost",
 "request": "launch",
 "args": [
 "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you so much for your help.
/Mike